# Existing data to new table, how to set up the PK & Identity

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, etl, identity

I am moving an Access app to SQL Server.  I have confirmed the data in the existing PK is unique so I want to copy it into the new PK Identity field.  The field is currently set as IDENTITY(1,1).  I know I can set the IDENTITY_INSERT for the insert period, but do I then need to adjust the IDENTITY start point so the next insert does not start at 1?  Example, the newest row in the existing data is id 4132, so do I insert the data then alter the column to IDENTITY (4133,1) ?

Answer (score 1):

This is simple enough to test on your own. Here's how:

Simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.whatever
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    Whatever VARCHAR(10)
);
```

Simple insert:

```
INSERT dbo.whatever ( Whatever )
SELECT x.Whatever
FROM   ( SELECT TOP 100 'A' AS Whatever FROM sys.messages AS m ) AS x;
```

Check on the max Id and current identity value:

```
SELECT MAX(w.Id) AS [max_id], IDENT_CURRENT( 'whatever' ) AS [ident_current]
FROM dbo.whatever AS w;
```

Both 100.

Do an out of band insert:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.whatever ON;

DECLARE @maxid INT = (SELECT MAX(w.Id) FROM dbo.whatever AS w);

INSERT dbo.whatever ( Id, Whatever )
SELECT x.Id + @maxid, x.Whatever
FROM   (   SELECT TOP 100 ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY @@SPID ) AS Id, 'A' AS Whatever
           FROM   sys.messages AS m ) AS x;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.whatever OFF;
```

Check on stuff:

```
SELECT MAX(w.Id) AS [max_id], IDENT_CURRENT( 'whatever' ) AS [ident_current]
FROM dbo.whatever AS w;
```

Both 200.

Do another insert:

```
INSERT dbo.whatever ( Whatever )
SELECT x.Whatever
FROM   ( SELECT TOP 100 'A' AS Whatever FROM sys.messages AS m ) AS x;
```

Check on stuff:

```
SELECT MAX(w.Id) AS [max_id], IDENT_CURRENT( 'whatever' ) AS [ident_current]
FROM dbo.whatever AS w;
```

Both 300.

Hope this helps!